# How was I able to review an edit suggestion for a deleted question?

Tags: support, review-queues

Here is my review: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12003312

I went to check the question for more context and saw that it was deleted, so I assumed it was an audit. Though it turns out it wasn't, and my review went in without any fuss.

Edit per dupe;

This smells like a feature-request. Reviewing a suggestion to a deleted post seems a waste of time. IIRC, some flags may be handled automatically based on action taken in a queue, correct?